# Grails ajax functionality

Tags: ajax, grails, groovy, prototype, gsp

I'm fairly new to Grails and today was following a tutorial on spicing up Grails with Ajax (prototype).
The tutorial was simple quote of the day Grails app that would asynchronously fetch random quote from the db. I've spent almost 3 hours getting ajax to work, finally got it to work with weird outcome. Basically, ajax wouldn't work unless I put the following two lines to both gsp of the view and gsp of the layout:

```
<g:javascript library="prototype" />
<r:layoutResources />
```

I tried to put the above lines into either one, but that wouldn't work. It had to be in both places. Is that the expected behavior of grails?

Comment: which Grails version are you using?

Comment: that was grails 2.0.0. The book was about grails 1.1 though :)

Comment: oh. much has changed since that version. maybe you should also refer to the latest docs as you read concepts in the book

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but I was doing that. Particularly ajax example was pretty much the same as the official functionality. Perhaps there was something wrong with my configuration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's not the expected behaviour. Get the latest Grails version and use jQuery as described in the documentation: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#6.7%20Ajax

Prototype can also be used, but jQuery is preferred since Grails 2.0.

A simple `<g:javascript library="jquery" />` should then do the trick.

BTW: V2.0 is pretty new. Most tutorials and books are still refering to 1.3.7 . So if you run into problems, check the really fine manual. But don't get me wrong: most of the books and tutorials are still great and valuable - you should just consult the manual, too!